# Control bubble chart layer attributes in Highcharts rCharts

Tags: highcharts, rcharts

I have a population pyramid using the rCharts-highChart library implementation presented in [here](http://walkerke.github.io/2014/06/rcharts-pyramids/). I am trying to add a layer of bubble chart over the population pyramid. I have partial success in implementing it. The image below shows the chart I achieved.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2wPo.jpg)

I am not able to control some attributes of the bubble chart. I want datalabels to be displayed on the the bubble chart. However, the dataLabels are activated for the bar chart only. I want the dataLabels to be displayed on the bubble chart also. The code I use is below.

```
 n1 <- hPlot(x = 'Agec',
           y = 'Category',
           type = 'bar',
           group = 'HbA1c_levels',
           plotBorderWidth = 1,
           data = MyD.melt)

# Adding a series of bubble chart
n1$series(type = 'bubble',
          data = (as.numeric(as.character(MyD$low)))
n1$series(type = 'bubble',
          data = (as.numeric(as.character(MyD$high))))

n1$plotOptions(series = list(stacking = 'normal', pointPadding = 0, borderWidth = 0, dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE))) 
#dataLabels gets activated only for bar chart as shown in the figure
```

Further, the bubblechart is able to read the 'Y axis' when I specify a particular column from the dataframe as shown in the above code. I would want it to read the "X,Y,Z,name" attributes from a list or dataframe and then plot the bubbles. Any idea how it can be done?

Comment: Please post the data you are using or an exemplary data that will show the same problem. I have tried with `data = list(
 list(x = 1, y = 1, z = 10),
 list(x = 2, y = 2, z = 20),
 list(x = 5, y = 3, z = 30)
)` and dataLabels are printed (by default z value, so size, is visible).